# (<UIPopoverPresentationController: 0x7fdb10687050>) should have a non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs.'

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I created a navigation item button in the tab bar controller.

```
class TabBarContoller: UITabBarController,UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
 ...
        let languageBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "EN", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: #selector(Language))
      // navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [rightButton , languageBtn]
        navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([rightButton,languageBtn], animated: true)
```

i want to run this function when this button it checked, which will popover a view controller:

```
 func showLanguagePopOver(base: UIView)  {
        let popOverContent = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Languages")as! Languages
        popOverContent.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(150, 150)
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: popOverContent)
        nav.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
        let popOver = nav.popoverPresentationController
        popOver?.delegate = self
        popOver?.sourceView = base
        popOver?.sourceRect = base.bounds
        popOver?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 25)
        self.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

i tried to call it like that :

```
func Language()
{
  showLanguagePopOver(UIView)

  }
```

it didn't work, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change below line:

```
showLanguagePopOver(UIView)
```

with this line:

```
showLanguagePopOver(self.view)
```

Answer (score 2):

***Swift 5***

```
let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [link], applicationActivities: nil)
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
            controller.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
            controller.modalPresentationStyle = .pageSheet
        }
        vc.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Presenting a view controller is different in iPad versions, it requires you to assign some kind of source view otherwise it will crash.